# jqgrid in asp.net using json datatype

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jqgrid

i binded the jqgrid using 'data type=local' its working fine but now i want to bind jqgrid using JSON datatype.
can anybody help me.

Answer (score 1):

you'd have to create a web service to return JSON data. And, the JSON data you send back for jqgrid to consume has to have a particular structure. Please look at the link mentioned by Dyson. I think the last few lines says it all...of course you'd have to convert php to your asp.net language of choice.

Comment: +1 Although you don't HAVE TO use a webservice, it is a good idea,

Answer (score 0):

Look at the example [here](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html). Click on the Loading Data -> JSON menu item

You will see:

```
url:'server.php?q=2', 
datatype: "json",
```

The url is the page that will serve up the JSON, in this case with a parameter 'q=2' telling the page what JSON to fetch.

You can also point the url at a webservice that would return the JSON.